# MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer - Resume when application launches

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

The [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) `applicationMusicPlayer` runs independent of the iPod (or Music) app, which is what I want. It stops playing when the application goes into the background which is again what I want.

However, I would like it to resume playing when the application resumes. Currently I do this by calling the play method again, however this causes the audio to start from the beginning. Is there a way I can actually resume playing from where the audio left off? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the App Delegate's `applicationWillResignActive:` method, read the `musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime` property (declared in the MPMediaPlayback protocol) and store that value somewhere.  You could set up a property such as:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval playbackTime;
```

and assign it with:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *myPlayer =
    [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    self.playbackTime = myPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
    [myPlayer pause];
}
```

When the app is about to become active again, the App Delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method will be called.  Inside that method, set the currentPlaybackTime property.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *myPlayer =
    [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    myPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = self.playbackTime;
    [myPlayer play];
}
```